# How do I reference the current row in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a spreadsheet I'm trying to keep fairly clean. So I'm using a second sheet to do my math on, which is based on the location of info on the main sheet. The end result is that I have a column where:

G2 contains **=SUM('Sheet2'!A2,'Sheet2'!C2)**

G3 contains **=SUM('Sheet2'!A3,'Sheet2'!C3)**

etc. For about 500 rows. The problem is that if I enable a filter and change the order of the rows or even manually drag a row elsewhere, the contents of every cell remains the same. I want them to update, so that if G2 suddenly becomes G69, it automatically changes to say **=SUM('Sheet2'!A69,'Sheet2'!C69)**

I suspect the fact that I'm referencing another sheet but still want to update the row number automatically may make it even harder? But is there a way to do this? I tried **=SUM('Sheet2'!$A2,'Sheet2'!$C2)** but that didn't do the trick.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `INDEX` and `ROW`:

```
'Sheet2'!A2
```

will be

```
INDEX('Sheet2'!A:A,ROW())
```

**Note:** *Traditional usage of `INDIRECT` in these cases are better avoided as `INDIRECT` is known to interfere with built in spreadsheet optimizations. Convertion of `string` to `range` is also avoided.`INDEX` is also better suited for such range manipulations, because it supports arrays better(eg: `=INDEX(A1:INDEX(A:A,5))`) and always acts like a array formula.*

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a direct answer to your question?

Comment: @Enigmativity It's as direct as can be. I don't understand why you would think otherwise. If you don't understand something about the answer "specifically", I'll be glad to clarify it and update the answer.

Comment: The OP is summing two numbers. Going from `=SUM('Sheet2'!A3,'Sheet2'!C3)` to `=SUM(INDIRECT("Sheet2!A"&ROW()), INDIRECT("Sheet2!C"ROW()))` is a perfectly sensible way to do this. Introducing a `INDEX` function is just unnecessary and it opens the OP to the same issue on rows with columns. And you don't show how to actually sum the two numbers. It's not a good, clear, and direct answer.

Comment: @Enigmativity Thank you for clarification. I don't like `INDIRECT`. It's clumsy in a lot of ways - transformation from a string range to a actual range is bad, mainly due to volatility, which would remove inbuilt spreadsheet optimizations. `INDEX` is the right/more direct way to do this. `INDEX` is naturally suited to get the range, in this scenario.  *you don't show how to actually sum the two numbers.* I think even basic users understand how to sum.  I'm sure OP is a beginner and he still understood and accepted my answer. I'm sorry but you are not seeing the elegance of my answer :)

Comment: @TheMaster can you share a copy of your sheet? :) just kidding

Comment: @player0 I'll share a table :) (PS: never have I ever shared a sheet here in all these years)

Comment: @TheMaster - You make some good points. If only they were in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

use in G2 and drag down:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("Sheet2!A"&ROW()), INDIRECT("Sheet2!C"ROW()))
```

Comment: This seems to be a very good and direct answer to your question.

Comment: Enigma: "Direct answer". Me: "(Shocked pikachu face)It is `INDIRECT`, not direct!" 